# Is "chico" a common form of address for an older person?

Tags: vocabulario, coloquialismos

On a recent visit to Spain I was rather surprised when a waiter addressed me as *chico*. He was about forty years younger than me which made it seem quite incongruous. It was obviously intended in a friendly sense. It was in a bar in Arrecife in Lanzarote but he did not seem to have a Canarian accent, at least to my inexpert ears, so I do not think that is too relevant.

And just in case you are wondering those close to me assure me that I do not resemble Chico Marx so we can rule that explanation out.

Comment: Maybe is a courtesy way from the zone, for example in Mexico you would always be a "Joven" (young one) to the waiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just asked a close friend from Gran Canaria and he replied that **no, it is not common** in the Canary Islands (where both Lanzarote and Gran Canaria are).
It is true that men there may colloquially address each other as *muchacho* ("boy"; sometimes pronounced like *muyayo*), but a waiter addressing an old(er) person as *chico* does not seem to be common.

Also, in my experience, that is unheard of in the rest of Spain too. The usual way for a waiter to address an older customer would be *señor / señora*, *caballero* (for male customers), etc.

Comment: for me Chico sounds more like the type of language used in central America
I know there's a lot of Venezuelan communication between the canary islands and Venezuela, so maybe he the waiter was Venezuelan. 

I have a Venezuelan friend and he uses the word Chico to address people. also on this side of the sea it is known that Cuban people use the word "chico" a LOT.

Comment: @Mike - that sounds plausible, because we know that Venezuelans have been leaving the country for economic reasons.